# How to automate replacing textures in Blender via Python?

Tags: python, texturing, materials

I tried finding tutorials on how to do this, but can't seem to find one. If you know of one, could you please point me in the right direction please? Or even an add-on.

I am trying to learn how to automate a very repetitive task of swapping textures to create different SKUs of a couch for example. So I need to replace the wood and fabric textures of this model to generate 20+ SKUs that I can then batch render over night. At this current time, I am saving each blend file by hand after swapping each texture out by hand. Which takes up a lot of time, and is very very boring..

I've tried learning it from the blender console window, but every time I try to replace the textures it doesn't record any information for me to try and learn. Only when I save it out as a different SKU name.

Hopefully this all makes sense? I can try explaining further if need be as well!

Thank you!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=Script+change+texture

Comment: You can most likely automate this yourself, with very little knowledge of python. Simply open the Info panel and copy the functions you use to do it manually. Use those functions to loop through textures and change them automatically. You can write your script in the Text Editor and run it from there as well. Lots of tutorials on basics like this one and it will help you in the long run.